# Oracle Pivot rows to columns pattern matching

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I want to rearrange the rows to columns (in tbl2 below) to count the number of occurrences of EXEN for the EXEN col, and any code starting with MPA for the MPACODE column.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (select code from tbl2 where pidm='4062161')
PIVOT  (count(*) FOR (code) IN ('EXEN' AS EXEN, 'MPA%' AS MPACODE));
```

tbl2:

[image: tbl2]

Desired output:

[image]

Actual output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must perform an intermediate step to transform all `MPA%`to `MPA`see subquery `dt2`

```
with dt as (
select 'EXEN' code from dual union all
select 'MPA'||rownum from dual connect by level <= 10),
dt2 as (
select 
case when code like 'MPA%' then 'MPA' else code end as code
from dt)
select *
from dt2
pivot (
count(*) for
(code) IN ('EXEN' AS EXEN, 'MPA' AS MPACODE));

      EXEN    MPACODE
---------- ----------
         1         10
```

`PIVOT` perform an *equal* comparison (not `LIKE`), so this is not valid: `'MPA%' AS MPACODE` and the *reason* why the query fails.

Comment: What is the equivalent to tablename tbl2 in your code?

Comment: `dt` ist the result of `(select code from tbl2 where pidm='4062161')`, i.e. 1x `EXEN`and 10x `MPAn`. Sorry for the confusion. @D.Rattansingh

Answer (score 1):

for example:

```
  select
   count(case when code='EXEN' then 1 end) exen,
   count(case when code like 'MPA%' then 1 end) mpacode
     from  tbl2 where pidm='4062161';
```